# react-virtualized Table with CellMeasurer can only measure the height of the first column

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

I have a table with multiple columns and I want each row to be adjusted to the tallest cell. However, when I use CellMeasurer on each column only the height of the first column is considered

Comment: Could you add some code, or a demo

Comment: Sounds like maybe you're using the wrong column index for the cache. (`Table` extends `Grid` and renders 1-column rows. `CellMeasurer` works with `Grid` and expects unique row+column indices. If you're using it with `Table` columns you'll need to fake the unique column indices bit.)

Comment: @bvaughn I have the same problem. How to use `CellMeasurer` in `Table`? Neither `Table` nor `Column` has a `deferredMeasurementCache` prop.